# How to scale or slide right, left view together in left side ,no any gape in view

Tags: android

I am drawing a Linear layout in Android to display 2 view and used ScaleAnimation for scaling right to left.it is fine but webview is not scaling show how to can find exact solution.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
WebView webview;
    private ImageView iv;
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private float scale = 1f;
    LinearLayout first,secand,mainLayout;
    private GestureDetector SGD;
    float initialX, initialY;
    boolean border1=false,border2=false;
    ListView mobile_list;
    ScrollView scroll;
    float downXValue,downYValue;

    String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry",
            "WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X","Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry",
            "WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X","Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry",
            "WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X","Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry",
            "WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X","Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry",
            "WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X","Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry",
            "WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mobile_list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);
        scroll=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll);
        mobile_list.setAdapter(adapter);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.buckscountycouriertimes.com/news/horsham-pfos/pfcs-increasing-in-neshaminy-creek-widespread-in-northampton-wells/article_5ef4bcc8-300e-5f3a-b908-601e79422f49.html");
        webview.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        //setupWebView();
        first = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.first);
        secand = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.secand);
       // SGD=new GestureDetector(this);
        mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        /*first.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MainActivity.this) {
            public void onSwipeTop() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(border2) {
                    // int b1 = first.getWidth()/2+8;
                    int width1 = first.getWidth() + 150;
                    int height1 = first.getHeight();
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width1, height1);
                    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.rt);
                    //secand.startAnimation(a);
                    secand.animate().x(width1).y(0).setDuration(500).start();
                    //first.animate().x(width1).y(0).setDuration(500).start();
                    first.setLayoutParams(parms1);

                    border1=false;
                    border2=false;
                }
            }
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (!border1){
                    // int b = first.getWidth()/2+8;
                    int width = first.getWidth() - 150;
                    int height = first.getHeight();
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
                    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.lt);
                    secand.animate().x(width).y(0).setDuration(500).start();
                    // secand.startAnimation(a);
                    first.animate().x(-10).y(0).setDuration(700).start();
                    first.setLayoutParams(parms);

                    border2=true;
                    border1=true;
                }
            }
            public void onSwipeBottom() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
        webview.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MainActivity.this) {
            public void onSwipeTop() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(border2) {
                    // int b1 = first.getWidth()/2+8;
                    int width1 = first.getWidth() + 150;
                    int height1 = first.getHeight();
                    final     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width1, height1);
                    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.rt);
                    //secand.startAnimation(a);
                    //secand.animate().x(width1).y(0).setDuration(500).start();

                    // first.animate().x(5).y(0).setDuration(700).start();
                    first.setLayoutParams(parms1);
                    first.requestLayout();
                    ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.5f);
                    anim.setFillAfter(true);
                    anim.setDuration(900);
                    secand.startAnimation(anim);


                    border1=false;
                    border2=false;
                }
            }
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (!border1){
                    int b = first.getWidth()/2+8;
                    final    int width = first.getWidth() - 150;
                    int height = first.getHeight();
                    final   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
                    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.lt);

                    // secand.startAnimation(a);
                    //first.animate().x(-(80)).y(0).setDuration(500).start();
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //first.setLayoutParams(parms);
                            //first.requestLayout();
                            // secand.animate().x(width).y(0).setDuration(500).start();
                            //mainLayout.animate().x(-80).y(0).setDuration(500).start();
                            first.setLayoutParams(parms);
                            first.requestLayout();
                            ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                            anim.setFillAfter(true);
                            anim.setDuration(700);

                            secand.startAnimation(anim);

                        }
                    }, 0);

                    border2=true;
                    border1=true;
                }
            }
            public void onSwipeBottom() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });*/
        secand.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MainActivity.this) {
            public void onSwipeTop() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(border2) {
                    // int b1 = first.getWidth()/2+8;
                    int width1 = first.getWidth() + 150;
                    int height1 = first.getHeight();
               final     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width1, height1);
                    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.rt);
                    //secand.startAnimation(a);
                    //secand.animate().x(width1).y(0).setDuration(500).start();

                   // first.animate().x(5).y(0).setDuration(700).start();
                   // first.setLayoutParams(parms1);
                   // first.requestLayout();
                    ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.5f);
                    anim.setFillAfter(true);
                    anim.setDuration(300);
                    mainLayout.startAnimation(anim);


                    border1=false;
                    border2=false;
                }
            }
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (!border1){
                     int b = first.getWidth()/2+8;
                 final    int width = first.getWidth() - 150;
                    int height = first.getHeight();
                    final   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
                    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.lt);

                    // secand.startAnimation(a);
                    //first.animate().x(-(80)).y(0).setDuration(500).start();
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //first.setLayoutParams(parms);
                            //first.requestLayout();
                           // secand.animate().x(width).y(0).setDuration(500).start();
                            //mainLayout.animate().x(-80).y(0).setDuration(500).start();
                            //first.setLayoutParams(parms);
                            //first.requestLayout();
                            //ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(0.8f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
                            ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 1.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                            anim.setFillAfter(true);
                            anim.setDuration(300);
                            mainLayout.startAnimation(anim);



                            //anim.setDuration(0);
                             // webview.startAnimation(anim);


                        }
                    }, 0);

                    border2=true;
                    border1=true;
                }
            }
            public void onSwipeBottom() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
        /*webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
                return SGD.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });*/
    /*    first.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
                return SGD.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
        secand.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
                return SGD.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });*/
     /*   mainLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
                return SGD.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });*/
        // final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureListener());
        // webview.setGestureDetector(new GestureDetector(new CustomeGestureDetector()));
     /*   webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return GestureListener.
                int b = first.getWidth()/2+8;
                int width=first.getWidth()-20;
                int height=first.getHeight();
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(b,height);
                first.setLayoutParams(parms);
                int width1=first.getWidth()+20;
                int height1=first.getHeight();
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms1= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width1,height1);
               // secand.setLayoutParams(parms1);
                try {
                  //  Thread.sleep(5000);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.getMessage();
                }
                //RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms11 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width+20,height);
                //first.setLayoutParams(parms11);

                return false;
            }
        });

    }*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        switch (e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                // store the X value when the user's finger was pressed down
                downXValue = e.getX();
                downYValue = e.getY();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:{
                float currentX = e.getX();
                float currentY = e.getY();
                if (Math.abs(downXValue - currentX) > Math.abs(downYValue
                        - currentY)) {
                    Log.v("", "x");
                    // going backwards: pushing stuff to the right
                    if (downXValue < currentX) {
                        Log.v("", "right");

                    }

                    // going forwards: pushing stuff to the left
                    if (downXValue > currentX) {
                        Log.v("", "left");

                    }
                }
               break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

     }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        String LOGTAG="CAT";
        switch (getSlope(e1.getX(), e1.getY(), e2.getX(), e2.getY())) {
            case 1:
                Log.d(LOGTAG, "top");
                return true;
            case 2:
                Log.d(LOGTAG, "left");
                if (!border1){
                    // int b = first.getWidth()/2+8;
                    int width = first.getWidth() - 80;
                int height = first.getHeight();
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
                    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.lt);
                    secand.animate().x(width).y(0).setDuration(500).start();
                   // secand.startAnimation(a);
                    first.animate().x(-10).y(0).setDuration(700).start();
                    first.setLayoutParams(parms);

                    border2=true;
                    border1=true;
        }
                return false;
            case 3:
                Log.d(LOGTAG, "down");
                return false;
            case 4:
                Log.d(LOGTAG, "right");
                Log.d(LOGTAG, "left");
                if(border2) {
                    // int b1 = first.getWidth()/2+8;
                    int width1 = first.getWidth() + 80;
                    int height1 = first.getHeight();
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width1, height1);
                    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rt);
                    //secand.startAnimation(a);
                    secand.animate().x(width1).y(0).setDuration(500).start();
                    //first.animate().x(width1).y(0).setDuration(500).start();
                    first.setLayoutParams(parms1);

                    border1=false;
                    border2=false;
                }
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
  /*  @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        //method onTouchEvent of GestureDetector class Analyzes the given motion event
        //and if applicable triggers the appropriate callbacks on the GestureDetector.OnGestureListener supplied.
        //Returns true if the GestureDetector.OnGestureListener consumed the event, else false.

        boolean eventConsumed=SGD.onTouchEvent(event);
        if (eventConsumed)
        {
           // Toast.makeText(this,GestureListener.currentGestureDetected,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Action",GestureListener.currentGestureDetected);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;

    }*/
  private int getSlope(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
      Double angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y1 - y2, x2 - x1));
      if (angle > 45 && angle <= 135)
          // top
          return 1;
      if (angle >= 135 && angle < 180 || angle < -135 && angle > -180)
          // left
          return 2;
      if (angle < -45 && angle>= -135)
          // down
          return 3;
      if (angle > -45 && angle <= 45)
          // right
          return 4;
      return 0;
  }
    public static void expand(final View v) {
        v.measure(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

        // Older versions of android (pre API 21) cancel animations for views with a height of 0.
        v.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Animation a = new Animation()
        {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                        ? RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        : (int)(targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return true;
            }
        };

        // 1dp/ms
        a.setDuration((int)(targetHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
        v.startAnimation(a);
    }

    public static void collapse(final View v) {
        final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

        Animation a = new Animation()
        {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                if(interpolatedTime == 1){
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else{
                    v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int)(initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                    v.requestLayout();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return true;
            }
        };

        // 1dp/ms
        a.setDuration((int)(initialHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
        v.startAnimation(a);
    }
    private void setupWebView() {
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:MyApp.resize(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height)");
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });
        webview.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MyApp");
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void resize(final float height) {
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                webview.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, (int) (height * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)));
            }
        });
    }
    private int getScale(){
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();
        Double val = new Double(width)/new Double(5);
        val = val * 100d;
        return val.intValue();
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    tools:context="com.calkins.slide_right_to_left.MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="150dp">
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/secand"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/new_phone"
            android:layout_height="250dp" />
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"    >
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to sweep just like below image:

It is real image[image]

And I want to just like: [image]

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
   public void onSwipeRight() {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (border2) {

                    mainLayout.animate().x(5).y(0).setDuration(500).start();


                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            int x1 = first.getWidth()/2;
                            // int y=first.getHeight();
                            int rightShift = secand.getWidth();
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params=mainLayout.getLayoutParams();
                            params.width=rightShift;
                            mainLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

                        }
                    }, 450);
                    border1 = false;
                    border2 = false;
                }
            }



 public void onSwipeLeft() {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (!border1) {
                    int x1 = first.getWidth()/2;
                    int y=first.getHeight();
                    int rightShift = secand.getWidth() + x1;
                    mainLayout.animate().x(-x1).y(0).setDuration(500).start();
                final    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params=mainLayout.getLayoutParams();
                    params.width=2*rightShift;

                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mainLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
                        }
                    },1/2);

                    border2 = true;
                    border1 = true;
                }
            }
```